# Bug in Review Audit

Tags: bug, review-audits

While  go through the review, i got a [review audit](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/239162) and i found it easily before selecting the options.

[image]

This line clearly shows that it's an audit.And also it will be an opposite of the above line.

Is it's a bug?

Comment: No, it's not a bug; robo reviewers miss even that line.